# cake .htaccess rewrite almost working

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I'm having a problem with rewrite rules in my cake 2.2.0 app.

Mod_rewrite seems to be working as going here:

`myapp.com/listings` works

But links generated by cake construct this type of URL, which also work but are not being rewritten:

```
myapp.com/app/webroot/index.php/listings
```

I've tried a lot of posted options but nothing seems to work?

My apache config is set up as follows:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

All .htaccess files are standard from the cake install?

Webroot .htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

App .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Should I be looking at anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any one else looks at this, my problem was that this line in /app/Config/core.php was uncommented:

Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));

Commenting it out removed the abs URL /app/webroot/index.php/ from my URLs.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should be able to fix in cakephp when you generate your links. The htaccess files that you have won't change the links in your page content.

If for whatever reason, you can't do this in cakephp, then you can add this to your Webroot htaccess, right below the `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /app/webroot/index.php/([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

and that will redirect the browser to the shorter URL.

Comment: Thanks Jon, That is what I was thinking, but the urls are being generated like this from cake and I'm not sure where to look to modify them?